# Angularjs UI-grid cell resizing issues when resizing browser window

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

The text in my ui-grid cells are not sizing correctly.  Sometimes it happens when switching tabs, then going back to the tab with the ui-grid. Cell width seems to change. Some grids show only one cell, then the issues happens and shows all cells like in the image, but with the ellipsis ... issue. Can be fixed sometimes by maximizing or minimizing the browser window.

[uigrid fail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Se6Si.png)

[uigrid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CMN5d.png)

Comment: pretty hard to help you if you only provide 2 screens. Post your code, or even better a simplified interactiv version using something like https://jsfiddle.net/